# Azure pipelines: How to use a variable in resources section

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using variable in resources.pipelines.branch gives me an error

```
The pipeline is not valid. Unable to resolve latest version for pipeline PrimaryArtifact. This could be due to inaccessible pipeline or no version is available.
```

but I can hardcode the variable value to make it work. See this self explanatory code.

```
trigger:
  - None

variables:
  hardcodedName: "svatsalya/deployFeature"

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: GovernedTemplates
      type: git
      name: OneBranch.Pipelines/GovernedTemplates
      ref: refs/heads/main
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: PrimaryArtifact
      source: "MyPipeline"
      branch: "$(hardcodedName)"              #This doesn't work
      # branch: "svatsalya/deployFeature"     #This works
```

Comment: @Robert, yes, thanks, it cannot be done.